# Pig Filter out NOT Matches

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I have a bunch of strings that have various prefixes including "unknown:"  I'd really like to filter out all the strings starting with "unknown:" in my Pig script, but it doesn't appear to work.

`simpleFilter = FILTER records BY NOT(mystr MATCHES '^unknown');`

I've tried a few other permutations of the regex, but it appears that `MATCHES` just doesn't work well with NOT.  Am I missing something?

Using Pig 0.9.2

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It's because the `matches` operator operates exactly like Java's `String#matches`, i.e. it tries to match the entire String and not just part of it (the prefix in your case). Just update your regular expression to match the the entire string with your specified prefix, like so:

```
simpleFilter = FILTER records BY NOT(mystr MATCHES '^unknown.*');
```

Comment: Ah, thank you. I had tried `'^unknown*'` as well but had forgotten the `.`